# Проблема с построением БД

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
  db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_POROD + "( " + namePorod_tier + " TEXT  primary key )");


    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_DATA_RECOUNT + " ( " + id + " INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT , " + stepName + " INTEGER NOT NULL , " + namePorod_tier + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + countDrov + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,   " + countDel + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,   " + countSyx + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,   " + countTreesNotFelling + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,  FOREIGN KEY(" + namePorod_tier + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME_POROD + " (" + namePorod_tier + " )) ");
```

Нужно сделать связь 1 к M  1(таблица TABLE_NAME_POROD  поле namePorod_tier ):M(таблица TABLE_NAME_DATA_RECOUNT  поле  namePorod_tier )
При просмотре диаграммы показывает такую связь

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно наоборот

Comment: Дополните код, который формирует тексты запросов, собственно теми текстами, которые были сформированы.

Comment: *При просмотре диаграммы показывает такую связь* Мало ли что и как оно показывает. Смотрите на факты. А они таковы - FK создан в таблице TABLE_NAME_DATA_RECOUNT на таблицу TABLE_NAME_POROD. То есть на стороне "один" - таблица TABLE_NAME_POROD, на стороне "много" таблица TABLE_NAME_DATA_RECOUNT. Всё, как и требуется. Собственно и стрелка на скрине показывает то же самое - значения из нижней таблицы будут проверяться на предмет существования в верхней таблице.

Comment: я делаю insert в таблицу TABLE_NAME_DATA_RECOUNT и оно добавляет  хотя таблица TABLE_NAME_POROD пустая( например)

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте местами строчки, и перенесите объявление связи по ключу в эту строчку

`db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_POROD + "( " + namePorod_tier + " TEXT  primary key )");`

Должно получиться так:

```
b.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_POROD + "( " + namePorod_tier + " TEXT  primary key , FOREIGN KEY(" + namePorod_tier + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_NAME_DATA_RECOUNT + " (" + id + " ))");


    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME_DATA_RECOUNT + " ( " + id + " INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT , " + stepName + " INTEGER NOT NULL , " + namePorod_tier + " TEXT NOT NULL , " + countDrov + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,   " + countDel + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,   " + countSyx + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ,   " + countTreesNotFelling + " INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ) ");
```